# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Exec'

Tags: sql-server

Can you please tell me what is wrong in this query? I am trying to write a SQL query to create a table dynamically

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQLString =+ 'Create Table' + GETDATE() + '_' + 'Table' + '' + '(' + 'Column1' + ' ' + 'Nvarchar(50)' + 'Null' + ')' +

Exec @SQLString ;
```

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple issues with your string `@SQLString`:

1. You don't require `+` at the beginning and at the end
2. A date will not concatenate with a nvarchar without conversion (CAST or CONVERT)
3. Because your table will contain spaces you need to put the table name in square brackets: `[` and `]`.
4. You will be better off with `exec sp_executesql @SQLString`

So your script might work with this:

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLString = 'Create Table [' + CAST(GETDATE() AS NVARCHAR(30))+ '_Table]' + ' (' + 'Column1' + ' ' + 'Nvarchar(50) Null' + ')' 
PRINT @SQLString
-- Exec sp_executesql @SQLString
```

I'd recommend reading up on the [CREATE TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql) statement and on the [String Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql). Then carry on to the [Data Type Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine) documentation and have a glimpse at the [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) syntax.

Good Luck.

Comment: Right on the money here.   Also, does the | ' (' + 'Column1' + ' ' + 'Nvarchar(50) Null' + ')' | portion seem a bit excessive in the concatenation?  Technically it can just be | ' (Column1 Nvarchar(50) Null) ' | right.  I mean I see the value if the Column1 were a variable or parameter, but here it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes. That is why I left it out in the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

On technique - I prefer to write one string in the program or script and then use REPLACE to insert variable terms using token marks where they go, i.e.

```
SET @template = 
N'
CREATE TABLE @{table} 
(i int, j int)
;--x'
SET @table_name_q = QUOTENAME(<formula>)
SET @workstring = 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
                  @template
                , N'@{table}', @table_name_q)
                ...more lines as necessary
EXEC sp_executesql @workstring [ , @parameters, @parameter1, @parameter2, ...]
```

Sometimes I use my own "safe_exec" procedure which tests the string for ending with "--x" and not containing any "@{" left in by mistake, and raises errors for failing these tests, instead of proceeding to execute with sp_executesql.

Comment: I've got to be honest, this looks a bit cumbersome.  I see where you're going with it after reading it for a while, but you always want to code for the next developer to have an easy time maintaining your code when you hit the lottery jackpot.

Comment: I find my way is good for larger exercises - though now I remember, I have found it necessary to put a key in a comment inside the string, like /* @{table} = [DB01].[dbo].[Table_Year2016] */' for each of the tokens.  At run time of course it could be DB27 and Year2017.  Lately somehow I've done less of this work.  A colleague prefers %%TABLE%% as his token style in otherwise similar work; if I have to rewrite most of one of those, I'll change it to my style.  If he doesn't like that, he should have done it right  :-)

Comment: Hahahaha can't argue with that!